# g.raphael bar chart different color for each bar?

Tags: colors, customization, raphael, bar-chart

Is it possible to give each bar its own color in a g.Raphaël bar chart?

I'm fully able to change the color for the series.
But what I would like, is the first results of each series to have similar colors, the second of each series and so on.

I can't find much documentation about it, and I've tried a few headless experiments, but none have the effect I want.

Comment: Can you post some code, possibly a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), with your current attempts?  You should be able to do this, but it's going to take some effort getting it together.

Answer (score 3):

You can set options like this:

```
var custom_colors =["#ff0000","#00ff00","#0000ff","#ffff00","#ff00ff","#00ffff"];

r.barchart(x,y,width,height,[data], { colors: custom_colors });
```

Other options

```
var options : {
    legend : [],
    stacked: false, //Use this to stack your bars instead of displaying them side by side
    type: "soft", //round, sharp, soft, square,
    colors : custom_colors
}

r.barchart(x,y,width,height,[data], options);
```

You might want to define your colors in a function. Here is a function you can use:

```
function _getColors() {
    var byndColors = ["#ffc000","#1d1d1d","#e81c6e","#7c7c7c","#00aff2","#aaaaaa","#611bc9"];

    //some random colors
    var randColors = ["#77efac","#364f8a","#60cb94","#cf263b","#2471bb","#7fc398","#d2c66a","#2109dc","#66ad29","#9a9754","#640cdf","#257683","#d51e05","#4bb36e","#e7408a","#1ef173","#1756bc","#cff215","#15c2fb","#f010ab","#844a0","#c34021","#3e4cf2","#8e2864","#a28f5c","#a9d528","#7b1e43","#a5401c","#829813","#691ccd"]

    //combine them
    return byndColors.concat(randColors);

}
```

and use it like:

```
r.barchart(x,y,width,height,[data], { colors: _getColors() });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `attr` property of each path in `svg`

```js
r.barchart(x,y,width,length,[data]);

var colors =["#ff0000","#00ff00","#0000ff","#ffff00","#ff00ff","#00ffff","#552288","#228844","#a38643","#296583"];

// use jquery for easier way 
$("#holder svg path").each(function(index){
    $(this).attr("fill",colors[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify some colours and then make sure that data is an array of arrays where the index of the inner arrays are all 0 for all values but that index:

```
data = [[55, 0, 0], [0, 20, 0], [0, 0, 40]];

r.barchart(10, 10, 100, 220, data, {
    colors: [
        // Some colours
        "000-#d00-#900",
        "000-#f64-#c31",
        "000-#fc0-#c90",
        "000-#3a3-#070",
        "000-#2bc-#089",
        "000-#00d-#00a",
        "000-#808-#404",
        "000-#444-#000"
    ]
});
```

Here `r` is the Raphael instance. See http://g.raphaeljs.com/barchart.html